# Hierarchy nodes path generation based on full path

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm, python-2.7

I have an SQL Query that returns the full path from leaf to node by concatenating all the nodes that lead to the root node for example leaf 'H' is:

```
H-G-F-E-D-C-B-A
```

where A is the root node. This concatenated value is the id for leaf H since is the combination of all nodes that lead to this leaf and won't be duplicated, each node id along the path will be itself plus the concatenation of its ancestors:

```
H-G-F-E-D-C-B-A =>LEAF ID
  G-F-E-D-C-B-A
    F-E-D-C-B-A
      E-D-C-B-A
        D-C-B-A
          C-B-A
            B-A
              A => ROOT ID
```

The question is, I need an algorithm that can produce all the paths listed above but starting only from a string like H-F-E-D-C-B-A. All paths can be returned in an array of strings, language can be java, python or javascript, I'll prefer javascript for the current application but any language that can show the algorithm is fine.

Currently this is what I have in javascript:

```
var text = "";
var array =[];
var i=0;
var j=0;
var pathstring = 'H-G-F-E-D-C-B-A';
var pathleaf = pathstring.split('-');
for (i=0; i< pathleaf.length; i++)
{
 for (j=0; j< pathleaf.length; j++)
 {
 if(j-1>=0)
   array.push(pathleaf[j] +"-"+ pathleaf[j-1]);
 }
 if(i-1>=0){
 text += array[i] +"-"+ array[i-1] + "<br>";
 }
}
```

test returns this:

```
F-G-G-H
E-F-F-G
D-E-E-F
C-D-D-E
B-C-C-D
A-B-B-C
G-H-A-B
```

Comment: Do you mean you need to get all your `Leaf IDs`? How do you represent your tree? It seems you use a DB.

Comment: Tree will be represented in jsTree, The parent of node B-A is A, Parent of C-B-A is B-A and so forth. Yes i use a db but rather than a query I'm looking for an algorithm to run in the front side using javascript.

Comment: To clarify things further, you need to write a function that receives a string argument that represents the unique ID of a leaf, and returns a list of strings which represent the path from that leaf to the root node?

Comment: Exactly, the returned list from the function will look like the one in the example, have in mind the the leaf unique id is the concatenation of all ancestors in that order, therefor that's all we need to build its genealogy by following the same pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it in Java that you can probably adapt to Javascript.

```
static String[] leafIDs(String s)
{
    List<String> sa = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] ca = new char[s.length()];
    for(int j=0, i=s.length()-1; i>=0; i--,j++)
    {
        if((ca[j] = s.charAt(i)) == '-') sa.add(new String(ca, 0, j));
    }
    sa.add(new String(ca));
    return sa.toArray(new String[sa.size()]);
}
```

Or you can do it using a `StringBuilder`

```
static String[] leafIDsSB(String s)
{
    List<String> sa = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=s.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(c == '-') sa.add(b.toString());
        b.append(c);
    }
    sa.add(b.toString());
    return sa.toArray(new String[sa.size()]);
}
```

Test

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(String so : leafIDs("H-G-F-E-D-C-B-A")) System.out.println(so); 
}
```

Output:

```
A
A-B
A-B-C
A-B-C-D
A-B-C-D-E
A-B-C-D-E-F
A-B-C-D-E-F-G
A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H
```

Comment: Your answer is almost correct, the only thing is that to get the right structure the input string has to be reverted, in your code I entered "A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H" an the result is correct.. Can you change it so when input "H-G-F-E-D-C-B-A": 
A, A-B, A-B-C etc instead of H, G-H, F-G-H etc

Comment: It looks like you may have reversed the requirements? The problem is actually easier now and can be solved using a StringBuilder too. I've updated the code to produce the desired output.

Comment: Did not reverse the requirements, the question to the top remained the same, In my comment it should have been A, B-A, C-B-A see how A remains to the right as is the root. I accept your solution, thanks  SirRaffleBuffle

Answer (score 0):

After fighting with different approaches I came up with the solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>PATH STRUCTURE</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = "";
var i=0;
var j=0;
var pathstring = 'H-G-F-E-D-C-B-A';
var pathleaf = pathstring.split('-');
pathleaf.reverse();
for (i=0; i< pathleaf.length; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j< pathleaf.length; j++)
    {
        if(i-j>=0){
            text += pathleaf[i-j]+"-";
        }
        if(j===i){
            text = text.substring(0, text.length-1);
            text +="<br>"
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The returned text is:

```
PATH STRUCTURE
A
B-A
C-B-A
D-C-B-A
E-D-C-B-A
F-E-D-C-B-A
G-F-E-D-C-B-A
H-G-F-E-D-C-B-A
```

now is just a matter of instead of text pushing values in an array.